# USACO Greedy Gift Givers Java Scanner Error

Tags: java

Right now I'm working on the USACO problem Greedy Gift Givers.  Here is the problem statement:

A group of NP (2 ≤ NP ≤ 10) uniquely named friends has decided to exchange gifts of money. Each of these friends might or might not give some money to any or all of the other friends. Likewise, each friend might or might not receive money from any or all of the other friends. Your goal in this problem is to deduce how much more money each person gives than they receive.

The rules for gift-giving are potentially different than you might expect. Each person sets aside a certain amount of money to give and divides this money evenly among all those to whom he or she is giving a gift. No fractional money is available, so dividing 3 among 2 friends would be 1 each for the friends with 1 left over -- that 1 left over stays in the giver's "account".

In any group of friends, some people are more giving than others (or at least may have more acquaintances) and some people have more money than others.

Given a group of friends, no one of whom has a name longer than 14 characters, the money each person in the group spends on gifts, and a (sub)list of friends to whom each person gives gifts, determine how much more (or less) each person in the group gives than they receive.

Here is my code written in java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class gift1{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        //scan np
        Scanner sc = new Scanner("gift1.int.txt");
        int np = sc.nextInt();

        //scan friend names => String Array/Maps
        Map<String, Integer> initial = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        Map<String, Integer> total = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        String[] people = new String[np - 1];
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < np; i++){
            String d = sc.next();
            initial.put(d, 0);
            total.put(d, 0);
            people[counter] = d;
            counter ++;
        }

        //scan person into HashMap with initial money (initial amount of money)
        for (int k = 0; k < np; k++){
            String a = sc.next();
            int b = sc.nextInt();
            int c = sc.nextInt();
            initial.put(a, b);
            if (c != 0){
                total.put(a, b + total.get(a) - (b/c));
                for (int j = 0; j < c; j++){
                    String person = sc.next();
                    total.put(person, total.get(person) + (b/c));
                }
            }
        }

        sc.close();

        //print output
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("gift.out.txt");
        for (int p = 0; p < np; p++){
            pw.println(people[p] + " " + (total.get(people[p]) - initial.get(people[p])));
        }

        pw.close();

    }
}
```

Note that I've created files called gift1.in.txt and gift1.out.txt so that isn't the issue. When I try to run this code, it gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at gift1.main(gift1.java:8)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: give us the contents of gift1.in.txt

Comment: 5
dave
laura
owen
vick
amr
dave
200 3
laura
owen
vick
owen
500 1
dave
amr
150 2
vick
owen
laura
0 2
amr
vick
vick
0 0

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to do newline on stack overflow but everything should be on a separate line except for the 2 integers in a row like 200 3, which are on the same line with a space in between

Comment: Upon further testing, I've figured out for sure that the issue is the nextInt() function.  Is this function not defined for scanner?  next() works fine...

Comment: I have absolutely no idea why nextInt() doesn't work.  I tried the following code and it still gave me the same error:

Comment: import java.util.*;

Comment: public class main{

Comment: Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: int a = sc.nextInt();

Comment: System.out.println(b);

Comment: And it didn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

This is because you need to input and output `gift1.in` and `gift1.out` instead of `gift1.in.txt` and `gift1.out.txt`.